# Firebase database rules parents shadowing children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've got a problem, and i tried everything, but I couldn't find a solution. I've got a firebase database like this. Chats:

-chats
--0
---title=""
---lastmsg=""
---timestamp=""
--1
---title=""
---lastmsg=""
---timestamp=""

And then:

-members
--0
---uid0="true"
---uid1="true"
--1
---uid2="true"
---uid3="true"

Now, i have this java code to process the list.

```
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("chats");
             myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                String titolo = (String) child.child("titolo").getValue();
                String ultimomsg = (String) child.child("ultimomsg").getValue();
                Long timestamp = (Long) child.child("timestamp").getValue();
                Log.w(TAG, "Title is: "+ titolo);
                CHATITEMS.add(new DummyItem(child.getKey(), titolo, ultimomsg, timestamp));
            }
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyPersonRecyclerViewAdapter(CHATITEMS, mListener));
        }
```

Now, i want the user to be able to read the chats nodes only if the userid it's on the node member/chatnumber/userid. I tried in several ways to set a rule without success. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase user security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) docs provide a good instructional starting point to help understand how the different rules should be structured to secure data at specified paths. In your case, you want `/chats/$chat_id` path readable based on whether logged-in user's uid is present at `/members/$chat_id/$user_id`. To accomplish this, your security rules should be like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "chat": {
      "$chat_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('members/' + $chat_id + '/' + auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might want the `.write` rule to be false, in case you have a [Cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) write to that database path via the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#admin-sdk-authentication), so you can update to the appropriate values depending on when new chat messages are sent.